# Visual Studio 2012 Coded UI Testing of Web Application - Code coverage

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, coded-ui-tests

I have a web application. I am using VS 2012 Coded UI for testing the web application. I have recorded the test and running it, and it works fine. But the code coverage window gives code coverage of the test project only, it doesnt give code coverage of the website project and other dll project which is referred in the web project.

I have added the testsetting file in the solution and selected the same.

Any clue?

Comment: Same question? http://forums.asp.net/t/1851537.aspx/1?Coded+UI+test+and+Code+Coverage+for+ASP+Net+and+VS2012

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things to verify

a) Have you added all these assemblies into the code coverage configuration's list of assemblies via the testsettings?

b) Is your deployment of the web app happening as a part of your test run? If so then you should ideally have the "instrument in place" option selected