# VS 2013 - Code Coverage in Coded UI Tests against application hosted on IIS-Server

Tags: code-coverage, visual-studio-2013, coded-ui-tests

I have a MVC web application hosted on a remote server. I have created another solution and recorded Coded UI Tests on that app.
Now I want to know how can I measure the Code Coverage of the other application that my tests cover.
For now, Code coverage only shows the results for the test project.

So first question, Is it possible to get code coverage of a web app running on a different server?
(I would think not, because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14746164/test-code-coverage-for-web-service-hosted-remotely) thread)

Secondly, I tried to get the coverage by hosting the web app on my hosting it on localhost oon my machine, and bu running it from VS itself, but I am still unable to get any code coverage except the test dll itself.

- I've made a custom CodeCoverage.runsettings file as explained in this msdn article - [Customizing Code Coverage Analysis](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj159530.aspx)
- I tried copying both dll and pdb files of my web app into the same folder as the assembly .dll files.
- I provided the search path to the dll for my locally hosted application

```
<SymbolSearchPaths>
<Path>C:\inetpub\wwwroot\DaisyMBPublish\bin</Path> 
</SymbolSearchPaths>
```

Here is my [CodeCoverage.runsettings](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8004248) file.

Where am I going wrong with this? How can I get code coverage of my application?
**I was successfull in excluding my test dll using the `<exclude>`*

Threads I've been to:

- [Visual Studio 2012 Coded UI Testing of Web Application - Code coverage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12891370/visual-studio-2012-coded-ui-testing-of-web-application-code-coverage)
- [Issue with Code Coverage in VS 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16504992/issue-with-code-coverage-in-vs-2012)
- [Coded UI test and Code Coverage for ASP.Net and VS2012](http://forums.asp.net/t/1851537.aspx)
- [Running Coded Coverage with CUIT against assemblies (published web page) on a remote server](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ec32f3e5-7d91-4b62-a670-02a4636ddafd/running-coded-coverage-with-cuit-against-assemblies-published-web-page-on-a-remote-server)
- [MSDN - Customizing Code Coverage Analysis](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj159530.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Quoting **Crystal Zhu**'s answer from my msdn thread [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/47d06022-bac4-4815-83d9-ec00b89cb469/how-to-get-code-coverage-of-application-under-test-in-coded-ui-tests?forum=vstest)

As far as I know, VS will not be able to instrument the binaries for apps running on IIS, we can’t collect code coverage for the app hosted on IIS as we normally do in VS2013. There are some approaches to accomplish  your requirement. Reference ‘IIS’ section in this blog: [Collecting Code Coverage Data when Running Web/Load  Tests](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/slumley/archive/2008/07/08/collecting-code-coverage-data-when-running-web-load-tests.aspx)

And AkshayGarg provided us detailed steps to collect code coverage for a web app/website published on IIS from running coded UI test in this thread:  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/57496eb5-6c36-4eb0-9f14-5a72562fcae6/how-to-get-right-code-coverage-in-coded-ui-testing?forum=vsautotest . You can try it.

Actually we also can collect code coverage metrics for ASP.NET applications running on Internet Information Server when we run coded UI tests from a lab environment in MTM.

Reference:  [Walkthrough: Using Code Coverage in Microsoft Test Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh698492(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using the Test Case Management features in TFS of scheduling test runs on a given environment. The way that this would work is that you would create a test suite with your automated test cases and then queue a run on an environment consisting of your server and your testbox. You can then configure the .testsettings of your server to enable code coverage while executing your tests from a different machine.

Refer these blogs which spell out the details

1. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/11/28/code-coverage-in-microsoft-test-manager-in-visual-studio-update-1.aspx
2. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/12/09/code-coverage-in-microsoft-test-manager-deep-dive.aspx

Comment: The problem is that we cannot use a _.testsettings_ file, We are using a _.runsettings_ file as I mentioned. I used the `<include>` section to add my dll of the application under test, but so far no success.

Comment: Have a look at my blog to see if you can get to the source of the issue using the .coverage file itself. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/allendm/archive/2012/06/05/troubleshooting-missing-data-in-code-coverage-results.aspx
Also you do not need "\.dll" in you settings just use ".dll"

Comment: Hey @allen Thanks for the link, great article. Can you please come to the chat room for a little discussion.
We'll post the findings here later.